# Using postcodes.io API on Django

Tags: python, json, django

I'm trying to achieve this:

> Use postcodes.io to get the latitude and longitude for each postcode
>   and render them next to each store location in the template

I have a series of postcodes into a `json` file:

```
[
{
  "name": "St_Albans",
  "postcode": "AL1 2RJ"
},
{
  "name": "Hatfield",
  "postcode": "AL9 5JP"
},
{
  "name": "Worthing",
  "postcode": "BN14 9GB"
},
{
  "name": "Rustington",
  "postcode": "BN16 3RT"
},
{
  "name": "Eastbourne",
  "postcode": "BN23 6QD"
}, ...
```

And so on...

I need to check on `postcodes.io`[0] the latitudes and longitudes of these postcodes, and render these coordinates next to the `json` result.

My question isn't about on how to render them, it's about on how to POST my json postcodes on their website, and get the respective latitudes and longitudes of each one.

I'm doing this on pure python, any ideas?

0.- https://postcodes.io/docs

Comment: This isn't really about Django then... what you need to do is make POST requests to the site with your postcode? Have a look at the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) which'll make it easy to do a POST request to the end point they specify and retrieve the data. If you need to stick to just the python stdlib, you'll need to look at `urllib.request` stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/). Try like this:

```
resp = requests.get('https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/BN14 9GB')
resp.json()
```

Or

```
data = {  
  "postcodes" : ["PR3 0SG", "M45 6GN", "EX165BL"]
}

resp = requests.post('https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/', data=data)
resp.json()
```

Integrate these with your json file:

```
json_data = open('path_to/postcodes.json').read()

for i in json_data:
    post_code = i.get('postcode')
    resp = requests.get('https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/{}'.format(postcode))
    i.update({'latitude': resp.json().get('latitude'), 'longitude': resp.json().get('longitude')})

print(json_data)
```